# How long can I stay in Panama? Passport stamp does not show a number of days

Tags: visas, eu-citizens, panama

I am an EU citizen and I got a tourist stamp upon arrival in Panama. However, this normally lists the number of days that this is granted (at least in other countries, in my experience). In this case no number was put in the stamp. Online I have read about 180 days and 90 days as a maximum so I am unsure what the case is for me.

Whatever the maximum number of days is, if I were to leave and re-enter, would this reset the counter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to wikipedia and its cited references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Panama), people from the EU and most other countries who may enter Panama visa-free can stay for up to 90 days.

The main exceptions are US and Canadian citizens, who may stay for 180 days, and people from countries which normally require a visa but who hold a multi-entry visa or permanent residence of certain countries, who may stay for 30.

Comment: Thanks. And if I leave and re-enter, would I get another 90 days? Or is that the maximum period per year?

Comment: @Twacc This is a question-and-answer site, not a discussion. While related to your original question, "reset" is a different issue, Further, information in Comments is not indexed, and therefore cannot be found by subsequent users. Please use the "Ask Question" button at the top to ask this as a new and separate question.

Comment: Apologies. This was part of my original question but went unanswered... should I not have asked this? I will in any case post it separately as instructed.

Answer (score 0):

> I am an EU citizen and I got a tourist stamp upon arrival in Panama. However, this normally lists the number of days that this is granted (at least in other countries, in my experience).

Schengen entry stamps don't list the amount of days, so that is not strictly true.

The Embassy of Panama in the United States states 3 months (see below) for persons (including EU citizens) who do not require a visa.

---

**Sources**:

- [IMMIGRATION AND VISAS - Embassy of Panama](https://www.embassyofpanama.org/visas-1)

> **NO VISA REQUIRED: IF YOU ARE FROM ANY OF THE FOLLOWING COUNTRIES**
>
> - The maximum amount of time that you can stay in Panama is **three (3) months**.
>
> ...
> [list of countries, including EU countries and UK]

Comment: "Schengen entry stamps don't list the amount of days, so that is not strictly true": an EU citizen's experience would not normally include Schengen entry stamps, so it is in fact true (inasmuch as it is a statement about OP's experience).