# Is the 90 day restriction in Panama per year or per trip?

Tags: visas, eu-citizens, panama

I am an EU citizen and I got a tourist stamp upon arrival in Panama. From [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/176683/how-long-can-i-stay-in-panama-passport-stamp-does-not-show-a-number-of-days/176691?noredirect=1#comment444882_176691) I understand I can stay maximum 90 days in Panama. The [linked source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Panama) does not elaborate on the exact details around the 90 days.

If I were to leave and re-enter, would this reset the counter? If the 90 days are only within a specific timeframe, what is that timeframe (calendar year? 12 months? etc)? Or is this one of those cases where it is ambiguous and up to the officer at the border to decide?

Comment: The source clearly says "stays of 90 days", meaning it's per trip. But that doesn't mean you can just leave Panama after 90 days and come back and stay another 90 days. Unfortunately I don't know the rules about returning.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. There may be no explicit rules about returning. Rather, Panama Immigration might assess whether a person seeking entry is in effect living (or trying to live) in Panama using consecutive tourist entries. This approach is common in many countries.

Comment: According to a friend of mine who travels to Panama frequently - Panama immigration officers can be very picky over who they admit.  My friend has been denied entry a couple of times (he enters Panama by land though, so it may be different arriving by air)

Comment: Like in many other places, there does not seem to be a hard limit. But a tourist is an "_extranjero que ingresa **ocasionalmente** en el territorio nacional, que **no tiene ánimo de establecer su residencia en éste ni de abandonar su residencia de origen** mientras se encuentre en Panamá, y que debe contar con **recursos económicos propios y adecuados para mantenerse mientras dure su permanencia** y salir del país al expirar el periodo autorizado."_ So no, visa runs are probably not a good idea.

Comment: @jcaron, please post as an answer and provide translation.

Comment: approximately: "a foreigner who occasionally enters the national territory, who has no intention of establishing their residency in it nor of abandoning their original residence while in Panama, and who should rely on their own sufficient economic resources to maintain themselves during their stay and to leave the country when the authorized period expires"